# Replacing boost::asio::async_read_some with boost::asio::async_read

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I was using the code sample provided by boost, the echo server, to try something with one of my client.
However, when I tried to replace the `boost::asio::async_read_some` with `boost::asio::async_read`, I noticed that the latter would only be called when the connection would be killed and read_some would be called any time a message would be sent from one of my client. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the original code 
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp

I replaced the content of do_read() with the following:

```
void do_read()
{

    auto self = shared_from_this();

boost::asio::async_read(socket_, data_, [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, size_t l) {
        if (!ec)
           do_write(l);
        });
}
```

Comment: `async_read` reads exactly `data_.size()` (?) data and calls the callback once it has read it all (or the input fails). `async_read_some` calls the callback after some data. What is your question?

Comment: @kamil cuk It actually could be that async_read is hanging, yet I am sending a single message to the server. Would async_read_until be a better option?
Basically I wanted to replace read_some with read as read_some can trim messages

Comment: `read_some can trim messages` - you should check if you read a whole message, if you did, then parse, if you didn't, save the data somewhere and wait to be called again. It really depends how you want the asynchronous operation to work. Is each message the same length or does the length differ? Same length - use `async_read()` - the length differs - use `async_read_some()` and wait for "message delimeter" or something like that. Use`async_read_until()` if you can write your condition to support it. If your message is trimmed, indeed you can specify the condition with `async_read_until()`